# Is there a catgorical encoder that allows me to specify the starting point(i.e. not 0)? or make specific values off limits?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, scikit-learn

I'm encoding some categories but my program see's 0 as a special value so I do not want it used. I figured out how to retain NaN's when I encode my dataframe but it's starting at 0.

How can I avoid it?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'city':    ['London','Paris','Moscow', 'London', 'NYC', np.nan],
                   'size':    ['M',     'M',    'L', np.nan,     'M',    'L'],
                   'quantity':[12,       1,      4, 5, 8, 10 ]})
catgoricalValues=['city','size']

df[catgoricalValues] = df[catgoricalValues].apply(lambda series: pd.Series(
    LabelEncoder().fit_transform(series[series.notnull()]),
    index=series[series.notnull()].index
))
print(df)
```

This is my result:

```
   city  size  quantity
0   0.0   1.0        12
1   3.0   1.0         1
2   1.0   0.0         4
3   0.0   NaN         5
4   2.0   1.0         8
5   NaN   0.0        10
```

You can see there are 0's in the result which will result in incorrect data when I do df.fillna(0) to convert NaN to 0. Short of building my own encoder is there anything I can do?

Comment: @anky I'm okay with any value as long as I can convert it back and it's not 0.  ideally, instead of starting at 0, it would start at 1 but if there is another solution I'd be open to it. any value != 0 for encoding is good.

Comment: I'm experimenting but the values returned for classes_ under label encoder is a np array..I wonder if I insert a 0 at the start of the array, then transform it will resolve my problem.

Comment: @anky yes. I will inverse_transform later in the script to save outcome.

Comment: okay, not familiar with scikit learn so much, hope you get a working solution, if not I will try tomorrow morning, I am guessing it would be better if you also post what you are trying to achieve(may be not required for ML experts but just saying)

Comment: @anky I wanted to make my question more universal to benefit others so I focused on the specific problem I have - label encoding where NaN needs to be a specific value. I feel introducing non-relevant areas for sake of context will add more complexity than needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own encoder to start from whatever number you like:

```
class MyLabelEncoder(LabelEncoder):
    def __init__(self, start=1):
        self.start = start
        
    def transform(self, y):
        return super().transform(y) + self.start
    
    def fit_transform(self, y):
        return super().fit_transform(y) + self.start
    
    def inverse_transform(self, y):
        return super().inverse_transform(y - self.start)

# Usage
encoder = MyLabelEncoder()
a = ['London','Paris','Moscow', 'London', 'NYC']
b = encoder.fit_transform(a)
c = encoder.inverse_transform(b)

# The encoded values start at 1
print(b) # array([1, 4, 2, 1, 3], dtype=int64)

# You can get back the original values
assert all(a == c)
```